# Why, Both radio buttons selected? i want single selection

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a radio question here I want select only one button to be selected. But here both buttons are got selected. kindly give me the solutions.

private void radioButtonQuestion(String radioquest, JsonArray optionsArray) {

```
    RadioButton radio;
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    JsonArray dependenciesArray = (JsonArray) indQuestions.get("dependencies");
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int a=0; a<optionsArray.size();a++) {
        JsonObject optionsObject = (JsonObject) optionsArray.get(a);
        JsonObject dependenciesObject = (JsonObject) dependenciesArray.get(a);
        String option = optionsObject.get("value").getAsString();
        list.add(option);
    }
    LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(context);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    cardview = new CardView(context);
    layoutparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutparams.setMargins(10,20,10,20);
    cardview.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
    cardview.setRadius(30);
    cardview.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    cardview.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    cardview.setMaxCardElevation(20);
    cardview.setMaxCardElevation(6);
    textview = new TextView(context);
    // textview.setLayoutParams(layoutparams);
    textview.setText(radioquest);
    textview.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 14);
    textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    textview.setPadding(15, 25, 25, 15);
    textview.setGravity(Gravity.NO_GRAVITY);
    ll.addView(textview);
    for(int i = 0; i< list.size();i++) {
        radio = new RadioButton(context);
        radioGroup = new RadioGroup(context);
        radio.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12);
        radio.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
        radio.setId(i);
        radio.setText(list.get(i));
        radioGroup.addView(radio);
        ll.addView(radioGroup);
    }

    ll.setId(id);
    cardview.addView(ll);
    cardview.setId(id);
    cardview.setTag("Radio "+id);
    id++;
    relativeLayout.addView(cardview);
}
```

Comment: Do not create `RadioGroup` inside loop create it only once outside loop . Right now each radio button has its own group . create it only once and add all buttons to same parent . it should work then

Comment: @ADM. Not yet. What about `ll.addView(radioGroup);` inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Your code created a different group for each individual radio button, that's why each can be selected at the same time. Each group can have one selected radio button. Instead, you should create just one group, and add all the buttons to that group.

Answer (score 0):

Just place radioGroup before options like below

```
 radioGroup = new RadioGroup(context);

 for(int i = 0; i< list.size();i++) {
        radio = new RadioButton(context);
        radio.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12);
        radio.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
        radio.setId(i);
        radio.setText(list.get(i));
        radioGroup.addView(radio);
        ll.addView(radioGroup);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

From the reference from your code, I am able to find the cause which produces this issue, You need to put this line(**ll.addView(radioGroup)**) out of for loop as below :

```
//...

        for(int i = 0; i< list.size();i++) {
            radio = new RadioButton(context);
            radioGroup = new RadioGroup(context);
            radio.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12);
            radio.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
            radio.setId(i);
            radio.setText(list.get(i));
            radioGroup.addView(radio);              
        }
    
     ll.addView(radioGroup);

//...
```